# Return averageifs of durations formatted to display only minutes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of durations formatted as "hh:mm:ss".

I use AVERAGEIFS to return the average of the durations that also match a particular date.

For example, I have the following formula in `E2`:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(
   $B$2:$B$12, $A$2:$A$12, D3)
```

The formula works but I want the result displayed in minutes only.

I tried using the HOUR function but it requires 3 arguments.

Can anyone help to convert the formula results in `E2:E3`
(highlighted in yellow in the image) into minutes without removing the AVERAGEIFS formula?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Basic Formula in `E2`

Ensure `E2:E` is formatted as **number**, not **duration**

```
=1440 * AVERAGEIFS(
   B$2:B, A$2:A, D2)
```

## Multi-Row Formula in `E2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(LEN(D2:D),
     1440 * AVERAGEIFS(
       B2:B, A2:A, D2:D)),))
```

## Explanation

#### Basic Formula

1. The result of your AVERAGEIFS function in `E2` is the duration  `0:06:15`.
2. Sheets stores durations as decimal numbers equal to the equivalent fraction of a day (max 15 digits of precision).
   For example, `0:06:15` is stored as `0.00434027777777778` because  `6.25` minutes is equivalent to `0.00434` days.
3. To change the stored number to fractions of minutes, instead of fractions of days, simply multiply the number by 14,400, the number of minutes in a day.
4. AVERAGEIFS's `average_range` and  `criteria_range` arguments where changed to infinite ranges, `B$2:B` & `A$2:A` instead of `B$2:B$12` & `A$2:A$12`. This way the formula will automatically include new dates and durations as they are added.

| Cell | Duration | Actual Number Stored | Stored * 14,400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E2 | 0:06:15 | 0.00434027777777778 | 6.25 |
| E3 | 0:12:27 | 0.00864583333333333 | 12.45 |

#### Multi-Row Formula

1. Wraps the **Basic Formula** in the ARRAYFORMULA function
2. Uses LEN in an IF function to check if each row in column D contains a lookup value.

   1. `value_if_true` argument is the **Basic Formula** but the AVERAGEIFS's `criteria` argument is now the range `D2:D` instead of the cell `D2`.
   2. `value_if_false` argument is an empty value.